# UserName parameter from ProfileParameter comes back null

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to call a method with the username of the logged in user. I have the following code.

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsFiles" runat="server" SelectMethod="getFiles" TypeName="MyProject.FileSystemBrowser">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ProfileParameter Name="username" PropertyName="UserName" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

When I debug, and look at the `getFiles` the `username` parameter is null.

I suspect it has to do with my web.config setup, so here's the profile section from it.

```
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
```