# MySql Membership Id as Query Parameter

Tags: mysql, asp.net

How do I use the Id of the current user as a parameter for a query in a asp page?

I'm using MySQL as a provider for membership and roles so should be able to access the user Id of the current user.

I want to do something like this but I get an error 'System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'

1. If it is not Id what would it be?
2. Is it Name or PropertyName that links to @Id in my query?

   ```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT Date, Distance, LongestActive, ActiveTime, Km, StepCount, SiteUserId FROM UpMoves WHERE SiteUserId = @Id AND Date BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-10-31' ORDER BY DATE ASC">
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ProfileParameter Name="Id" PropertyName="Id" Type="Int32" />
   </SelectParameters>
   ```

Following codingstills comment and link I now have the following code in Page_Load

```
        System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
        System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase profile = System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
        profile.SetPropertyValue("SiteUserId", user.ProviderUserKey);
        profile.Save();
```

and added to my web config

```
  <properties>
    <add name ="SiteUserId" type="Int32"/>
  </properties>
```

and now this works

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Date, Distance, LongestActive, ActiveTime, Km, StepCount, SiteUserId FROM UpMoves WHERE SiteUserId = @SiteUserId AND Date BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-10-31' ORDER BY DATE ASC">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ProfileParameter Name="SiteUserId" PropertyName="SiteUserId" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

but I cannot help thinking there must be an easier way - but maybe not.

Comment: Perhaps this thread is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013181/username-parameter-from-profileparameter-comes-back-null

Comment: Could be the answer - it works but seems a bit inelegant? I've learnt something anyway so thanks